# Identify Ball Bearing for Replacement

Tags: identify-a-tool, ball-bearing

I am needing to replace a broken ball-bearing for the Robot-Coupe CL50 D Ultra. Unfortunately, the company has been unable to send me the correct manual. Perhaps they do not have it, because there is a newer version (E) available only, which does not list this part.
I am hoping to be able to identify the part in another way. Here is the image and measurements:
[image: unidentified ball-bearing for the Robot-Coupe CL50 D Ultra]

Anyone able to identify this? The image shows a rough schematic with sizes in millimeters. It is in place to help rotate the central shaft of the cutting blades. The other ball-bearing in use is the SKF 6004RS.

Any help is most welcome! Thank you very much,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Search for:

"nadella needle roller bearing"

and I think you'll find some similar products.

You will want to carefully measure your application and pick the closest match from the available choices.  My guess is that this is a standard hardware item and you should be able to match or cross it.

[image: NADELLA Needle Roller Bearing]

Looking at their catalog the RAX718 looks like it might be it:

[image: Nadella RAX718]